# Get all elements with the presence of a certain CSS property using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, browser

Is there a way to get all elements on the DOM with the presence of a certain CSS property? Say I wanted to get all elements with a background-image CSS value -- how could I select all of them? I preferably want to avoid using Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be absolutely sure, you have get the style like this:

```
var elms = document.all ? document.all : document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
    if ((elms[i].currentStyle && elms[i].currentStyle.backgroundImage.length > 0) ||
    (window.getComputedStyle &&
    window.getComputedStyle(elms[i]).getPropertyValue("background-image"))) {
        alert('found one!');
    } 
}​
```

CurrentStyle is for IE, getComputedStyle is for the rest.

Comment: Just for a curiosity, what'll be the result of this code, if `runtimeStyle` has been set for some element?

Comment: That is probably a very good question :-) I have never heard of runtimeStyle before, so I am not able to answer that, sorry

Comment: I'm not sure if it's IE-only, but in IE you can set `runtimeStyle` to make a kind of an inline style for an element. However this style can't be seen when retrieving  `innerHTML` or `outerHTML`, though it is rendered to the page.

Answer (score 2):

on a modern browser you can use [`getComputedStyles`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
var haveBg = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(elements[i], null);
    if (style.getPropertyValue("background-image") != 'none') {
        haveBg.push(elements[i]);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var elms = document.all ? document.all : document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
   if (elms[i].style.backgroundImage.length > 0) {
        alert('found one!');
    } 
}
```

It would be better to use the exact tag name rather then '*' if you know what it would be before hand

Comment: I'm not a hundred percent sure any more, but doesn't the `style` property only look at in-line styles (from the `style` attribute)?

Comment: @DavidThomas how would one get a non-inline style then? Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: True - I guess if you want to look inside the CSS you'd have to do it by hand using document.styleSheets - it would probably be pretty difficult   http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dynamic-style-css-javascript/